# Show Quantity with Quantity Breakdown by Batch numbers

Tags: sql-server

I have written a query in T-SQL that extracts StockNo, StockQty, CostPrice, BatchNo, BatchQty and StockValue. Something similar to a Stock Audit report. The BatchNo and BatchQty exists on TableB while the StockNo, StockQty, CostPrice and StockValue are from TableA. The BatchQty is the breakdown of the StockQty for Batched Items. So yes, the query returns the StockNo and it's relevant batch quantity if applicable. I am trying to write the query such that it shows the StockQty and next to that the BatchQty breakdown with duplicating or bringing in the StockValue again.

I am using SQL 2016.

I have tried different join types, temp tables as well as a union. I have also researched different SQL forums to see if there is a possible solution that I can use.

```
SELECT 
TRANS_ID
STOCKNO,
BATCHMANAGED,
BATCHNO,
STOCKQTY,
BATCHQTY,
COSTPRICE,
STOCKVALUE,
FROM TABLE_A T0
FULL JOIN TABLE_B T1 ON T0.STOCKNO = T1.STOCKNO AND T0.TRANS_ID = T1_BASE_ID
```

I had to go with a full join as I needed Stock items that were both Batched and Non-Batched. Any other join I tried, omitted certain stock items and the total Stock Value didn't balance back to the Trial Balance.

Below is the result I currently get, which is extracting the StockQty and StockValue twice and in certain cases more than twice depending on the BatchNo and BatchQty:

```
StockNo BatchManaged BatchNo StockQty BatchQty  CostPrice StockValue
Item1   Y        BN0001 20  10  10.00     200
Item1   Y        BN0002 20  10  10.00     200
Item2   Y        BN0003 40  24  30.00     1200
Item2   Y        BN0004 20  16  30.00     1200
Item3   N               50      20.00     1000

                    Total             3800
```

This is the output I am trying to achieve where the StockQty and StockValue is not shown for every batch number.They need to just show once:

```
StockNo BatchManaged BatchNo StockQty BatchQty  CostPrice StockValue
Item1   Y        BN0001 20  10  10.00     200
Item1   Y        BN0002     10  10.00   
Item2   Y        BN0003 40  24  30.00     1200
Item2   Y        BN0004     16  30.00   
Item3   N               50  20            1000

                          Total   2400
```

Comment: Apologies but the sample code and expected output did not show I wanted.This is only my second time using this forum

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It would be really helpful to have sample data and table structures. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is good example of what we mean.

Comment: @SeanLange - Thanks for editing my post :-). Sadly i cannot release the data or table structures of the actual query as it's under IP. The most I can do is supply the above data in a better format perhaps but the links are exactly the same as it is only 2 tables required for this query to work. So I've used the exact same linking as my actual query. To my limited knowledge it sounds a like an output format issue or something.

Comment: Well you would never share real data in this case. But without table structures and data that is representative of the problem this is tricky. But looking closer at your requirements this seems like a display thing, not a database thing.

Comment: @SeanLange - yes it is a display or format thing. I've been researching rollups. It looks like that might be the answer I'm looking for. If not then I'll have find another way to format the output.